# Accessing COM add-in code from VBA

Tags: com, excel, vsto, vba

I have created a COM add-in for Excel 2003 using Visual Studio 2005 Tools for Office.  The add-in code looks like this:

```
[Guid("EAC0992E-AC39-4126-B851-A57BA3FA80B8")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("NLog4VBA.Logger")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
public class Logger
{
    public double Debug(string context, string message)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(message);
        return message.Length;
    }

    [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void RegisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"));
        RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type, "InprocServer32"), true);
        key.SetValue("", System.Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\mscoree.dll", RegistryValueKind.String);
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void UnregisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"), false);
    }

    private static string GetSubKeyName(Type type, string subKeyName)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        s.Append(@"CLSID\{");
        s.Append(type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper());
        s.Append(@"}\");
        s.Append(subKeyName);
        return s.ToString();
    }
}
```

I've set the project to register for COM interop, and I've registered the DLL with:

```
regasm.exe /tlb NLog4VBA.dll
```

When I open Excel, I go to Tools -> Add-Ins, click Automation, and add NLog4VBA.Logger.  I can then go to Insert -> Function, pick NLogVBA.Logger from the list of categories, and choose Debug.

The end result is a cell with contents like:

```
=Debug("My Context","My Message")
```

... and a displayed value of:

```
10
```

This is all as it should be.  In my VBA code, I can go to Tools -> References and add NLog4VBA.  I then add the following code to a button on my sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        Application.COMAddIns("NLog4VBA.Logger").Object.Debug "My Context", "My Message"
End Sub
```

This fails, because COMAddIns("NLog4VBA.Logger") fails with:

```
Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range
```

Could someone please tell me what I need to do to make the Debug() method accessible to my VBA code (which is more useful to me than being able to call the method from within a cell)?

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

*Edited 2010/09/07:* I've updated the code snippet to include the [ProgId] attribute as suggested below by Jim; the problem persists.  I can see the object in registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EAC0992E-AC39-4126-B851-A57BA3FA80B8}]
@="NLog4VBA.Logger"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EAC0992E-AC39-4126-B851-A57BA3FA80B8}\Implemented Categories]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EAC0992E-AC39-4126-B851-A57BA3FA80B8}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EAC0992E-AC39-4126-B851-A57BA3FA80B8}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mscoree.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Both"
"Class"="NLog4VBA.Logger"
"Assembly"="NLog4VBA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/projects/nlog4vba/NLog4VBA/bin/Debug/NLog4VBA.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EAC0992E-AC39-4126-B851-A57BA3FA80B8}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0]
"Class"="NLog4VBA.Logger"
"Assembly"="NLog4VBA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
"RuntimeVersion"="v2.0.50727"
"CodeBase"="file:///C:/projects/nlog4vba/NLog4VBA/bin/Debug/NLog4VBA.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EAC0992E-AC39-4126-B851-A57BA3FA80B8}\ProgId]
@="NLog4VBA.Logger"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EAC0992E-AC39-4126-B851-A57BA3FA80B8}\Programmable]
```

Also, the ProgID is visible in the Add-Ins dialog:

[image: Add-Ins dialog showing ProgID]

I still have no idea why this isn't working :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my VBA code was quite wrong; [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/isvvba/thread/2da9e25e-dc05-444c-a309-8c1cb52f1d84) is the answer courtesy [Jan Karel Pieterse](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/jan%20karel%20pieterse/):

> I think you would need to do something
>   like this:
>
> ```
> Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
>
>         'Declare an object variable using the referenced lib.
>         'if all is well, intellisense will tell you what the proper object name is:
>         Dim objLogger as NLog4VBA
>
>         'Create an instance of the object
>         Set objLogger = New NLog4VBA
>
>         'Now use the object
>         objLogger.Object.Debug "My Context", "My Message"
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The COMAddIns collection is either indexed via a numerical index, or via a string that is the *ProgId* of the desired component. Make sure that your ProgId is actually "NLog4VBA.Logger" (via the `ProgId` attribute in .NET) and verify that the object is registered with this id (which you can easily check in the registry, searching for your assigned GUID).

Comment: Jim: thanks for the suggestion, but it's still failing.  I've updated the snippet with the attribute, and included a dump of the related registry key.

Comment: Take a look at Osterman's blog, he explains the minimum set of registry keys needed for a ProgId to work:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/01/10/511279.aspx - it would seem you are missing  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NLog4VBA.Logger and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\NLog4VBA.Logger\CLSID, actually the two Larry calls "minimal set of registry keys needed for a progid". You can try manually adding those two for a start and see if it helps.